# Taking the derivative of a product, which is made up of two quotients

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm working on a calculus question, where we're asked to find $g'(z)$ for
$$g(z)=\frac{z^2-2z-8}{z-3}\cdot\frac{z^2-9}{z-4}$$
So I was thinking that first you have to use the quotient rule on each side individually and then multiply them, but I seem to keep getting stuck and it's becoming pretty frustrating.

Comment: Product rule quotient rule combo deal.

Comment: Have you tried canceling anything first?

Comment: ah, apply quotient rule and to each and then product rule? I hadn't tried cancelling anything either actually.

Comment: Well, cancelling is going to be easier...

Comment: I'll give that a go, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your problem simpler by hand first before bringing in the machinery.
$$g(z)=\frac{z^2-2z-8}{z-3}\cdot\frac{z^2-9}{z-4}=\frac{(z-4)(z+2)}{z-3}\cdot\frac{(z+3)(z-3)}{z-4}=(z+2)(z+3)=z^2+5z+6$$
$$g'(z)=2z+5$$

Comment: now that's helpful. Thank you! I wouldn't have realized that it could have been solved so easily.

Answer (score 1):

First,let's factor and simplify:
$$\frac{(z-4)(z+2)}{(z-3)}\cdot\frac{(z+3)(z-3)}{(z-4)}=(z+2)(z+3)=z^2+5z+6 \implies g'(z)=2z+5$$